# "Продукция доступна в пятнадцати покрытиях."

Tags: стилистика

"Продукция доступна в пятнадцати покрытиях." Правильно написано?

Comment: Формально правильно, но непонятно. В смысле - в пятнадцати каких-то ипостасях?

Comment: Да, о чём вообще речь?

Answer (score 1):

Формально это означает, что имеющаяся в продаже продукция чем-то покрывается пятнадцатикратно или -слойно, и можно подумать, что без этого она не отпускается. Лучше сказать "*(продукция предлагается) в 15 вариантах покрытия*".